# Sql server performance changes after recreating the procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

We have a main stored procedure that returns around 1000 records, changes by the user permissions.
Lately the procedure performance became very bad - but only from the web-service - more than a minute! 
but when running the same SP with the same parameters from ssms took only 3 seconds!!
When I tried to check the problem I added writes to log table, and immediately this change improved the performance again to 3 seconds from the web-service.
This is a mystery for me:
1. The difference between running from web-service and ssms
2. The change after adding the logging

Comment: Sounds like a typical parameter sniffing issue

Comment: 99% parameter sniffing

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is called `parameter sniffing`. There were 2 execution plans for this procedure, one created the first time you launched it from web server and another created when you lanuched it from SSMS. And the parameters of these two plans were different. The next time you execute this proc, one of this plans is used: when you execute from SSMS, the second plan is used, and from web service the first plan is used. The parameters passed to this proc were atypical when executed from wb service, and typical when executed from SSMS.

When you altered your procedure, those 2 plans were invalidated as the procedure has changed, then the new execution plan was built for SSMS and for web service, this times both plans were made for the same or similar paremeters.

If you could extract old plans from plan cache you'd see they were different and the parameters sniffed also were different while now the plans are the same and parameter sniffed are the same or similar.

Here you can read more on parameter sniffing: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: This explains the "mystery", it doesn't show a clear solution to the problem apart from a link. Perhaps you could elaborate a little bit on possible solutions?

Comment: ... and this can also happen if you use the _same_ parameters!! It won't use the same bad cached plan (and therefore won't reproduce the issue in SSMS) if you use different `SET` options, like `ARITHABORT` for example! Took me a long painful time to work this out so I post it every chance I get.

Comment: Short answer: add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to your SP. But you should understand the problem properly and consider more thorough solutions. i.e. search for that in the linked document and read further

Comment: It can be also OPTIMIZE FOR, maybe OP cannot permit to recompile every time. The fact is now there is only a good plan, and we neel the bad plan too to make the investigation

Comment: >>>and this can also happen if you use the same parameters!!<<< The parameters at the compilation time was surely different, SET options was only the cause of another plan creation (instead of using already created plan that was created for a session with DIFFERENT options), but if the plan is different, it's not due to SET options, it's due to DIFFERENT parameters at the first compilation

Comment: I mean the same parameters between the web service and SSMS: "when running the same SP with the same parameters from ssms took only 3 seconds!!". I'm not talking about the compiled plan parameters and the slow execution parameters. I'm explaining why a seemingly identical bit of SQL uses a bad execution plan in the web service, and generates a new (fast) one in SSMS

Answer (score -3):

Please do not use functions on TOP, on recordset, and, on WHERE/JOIN clauses.
When youre calling SP from SSMS, server optimizes it. But, when calling from frontend, it is huge problem. So, eliminate functions, if possible.

If you want to view about what im talking, please start profiler and then log RPC starting/completed, sql statament events. Call quantity is same, as recordset. So, assume, youre calling procedure 1000 times when usig FN on statement , returning recordset.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what and how exactly SP are optimized when running from SSMS/how is it different when calling from code

Comment: @evictednoise there isn't any difference in the optimisation process that means SSMS receives "better" optimisation than some other app.

Comment: Thanks for downvotes! @Sarah, as you said, its ok, when youre inserting to log table(and still calling from frontend) instead of returning records to frontend. So, our colleagues are wrong here, its not 'sniffing' problem. 
Please review your FN usage, as I said.